# Notepad++ to enter new line and not get indented hotkey?

Tags: notepad++, hotkeys, indent

Auto-indent in Notepad++ sometimes turns out to be very annoying - e.g. when we work with text/note file.

Very often do I want to enter a new line and the cursor is NOT indented i.e. at the beginning of the line.

Lovely to have it with `Ctrl-Enter`. How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is `Insert Blank Line Below Current`.

I know, it's a handful. You can change this, just go to **Settings** → **Shortcut Mapper** → scroll down and it's #62 **Insert Blank Line Below Current**.

Comment: I tried changing the shortcut to `Ctrl Enter` but not succeed. Though Ctrl-Alt for the `Above Current` one works enough for me. Thanks a lot!